# Eager loading doesnt include has_one associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have 3 models:

```
class Opportunity
   include Mongoid::Document
   ...
   ...

   has_many :proposals
end

class Proposal
   include Mongoid::Document
   ...
   ...

   belongs_to :opportunity
   has_one :risk

   scope :eager, ->{ includes([:opportunity, :risk]) }

   def as_json(options={})
    attrs = super(:include => [:opportunity, :risk])
    attrs
  end
end

class Risk
   include Mongoid::Document
   ...
   ...

   belongs_to :proposal
end
```

If I now do try eager load and render the result:

```
render json: {result: Proposal.eager.first()}
```

I get the proposal record including the opportunity but the risk record is missing. Am I doing something wrong??

Also doing Proposal.includes(:risk, :opportunity).first() doesnt include the record from Risk. I checked the database - the record is there. And when I look at the risk_id field it has the right id there. I thought I can do eager loading with has_one relationships?

Any idea?

Comment: FYI, Rails already has built-in support for "includes" when using `as_json`. See [HERE](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

Comment: Hi in reality my code is more complex - I create my models dynamically. I tested now with the static model on the console and all works fine. The same code with the dynamic classes (identical as_json function) doesnt work.

Comment: I also seem to end up at different code bases when using rails server and rails console! But I am in both cases in the development environment

Comment: From what you said above, why is it named `risk_id` when you said "And when I look a the risk_id field...". Shouldn't the field be named as `proposal_id` instead because risk belongs_to proposal?

Comment: No - risk_id in proposal record. Anyway - I am really confused now since calling certain methods in rails console lead to different results thant rails server

Comment: if `risk_id` is a field in proposal collection, then you'd want to use `Proposal` `belongs_to :risk` instead of `has_one :risk`